# Facebook Ads page_welcome_message invalid for ads with Messenger as destination

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-ads-api

trying to run a 'Traffic' ad to a Facebook Messenger bot.
In order to initiate the bot conversation I need to use the 'Get Started' button as part of the messenger ad conversation and therefore need to use the "Structured Message (JSON)" option.
I cannot submit the ad since it always fails with this error

"Invalid Page Welcome Message for Messenger Destination Ads: The Message Text (page_welcome_message) is invalid for ads with Messenger as destination."

It's unclear what "page_welcome_message" is and where to set it.

I tried researching the FB community and tried to reach out but to no avail - although I did find other people with the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the JSON that Facebook creates using the "Quick Creation" feature is causing the issue.
With a manually created JSON, I'm able to submit the ad successfully.